# ActionScript 3 - identifying a substring

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have an xml file (edit below) which includes data on some European countries:

```
xmlData = <dataSet>
 <recordSet>
    <rd id="Austria">12.3,12.6,12.0,12.4,12.0,12.1,12.6</rd>
    <rd id="Belgium">14.8,14.7,15.2,14.7,14.6,14.6,15.3</rd>
    <rd id="Bulgaria">14.0,18.4,22.0,21.4,21.8,20.7,22.3</rd>
    <rd id="Cyprus">16.1,15.6,15.5,15.7,15.3,15.3,14.5</rd>
    <rd id="Czech Republic">10.4,9.9,9.6,9.0,8.6,9.0,9.8</rd>
    ... 
 </recordSet>
 </dataSet>
```

I need to be able to isolate the country name as a variable so that I can later say 
'if country = Austria, do this'.

How do I go about this please?

Thank you,

Bruce

Comment: How do you parse your XML?

Comment: What does that mean?  I'm adapting someone else's code. Thanks.

Comment: I guess this is what you mean: the xml file is loaded within a function 'onVarLoad'
 xmlData=new XML(evt.target.data);

Comment: Lookup e4x. AS3 supports it and it allows you to query your XML easily

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic object like that:

```
var xmlData:XML = <dataSet>
        <recordSet>
            <rd id="Austria">12.3,12.6,12.0,12.4,12.0,12.1,12.6</rd>
            <rd id="Belgium">14.8,14.7,15.2,14.7,14.6,14.6,15.3</rd>
            <rd id="Bulgaria">14.0,18.4,22.0,21.4,21.8,20.7,22.3</rd>
            <rd id="Cyprus">16.1,15.6,15.5,15.7,15.3,15.3,14.5</rd>
            <rd id="Czech Republic">10.4,9.9,9.6,9.0,8.6,9.0,9.8</rd>
        </recordSet>
    </dataSet>

var map:Object = new Object();
for each (var countryXML:XML in xmlData.recordSet.rd)
{
    map[countryXML.@id] = countryXML.toString();
}
```

Now, you can write your condition:

```
if (country == "Austria")
{
    //do smth
    trace(map[country])
}
```

Comment: How does "countryXML" isolate the text between the quotes? And why do I need an 'object' rather than a string, or text field please?

Comment: Object is simple to store variables by key value like country. Dont understand, what text do you want to isolate?

Answer (score 1):

```
xmlData.recordSet.Austria;
```

That's it...
If it's not a single word:

```
xmlData.recordSet["Czech Republic"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response. I was away from my desk for an hour. I need to isolate just the country name e.g. Austria. In some cases this will be two words. By 'between the quotes, I meant as below Cyprus and Czech Republic

```
        <rd id="Cyprus">16.1,15.6,15.5,15.7,15.3,15.3,14.5</rd>
        <rd id="Czech Republic">10.4,9.9,9.6,9.0,8.6,9.0,9.8</rd>
```

OK - thanks. I think though what I need is to know what the * generic term * is for the bit which, in this case is the name of various countries.

```
        <rd id="WhatAmICalled">16.1,15.6,15.5,15.7,15.3,15.3,14.5</rd>
```

so that I can then interrogate thus:

```
        if  (WhatAmICalled == Austria) 
            {eat a strudel}
        else ...
            {   }
```

In other words, what is the element 'WhatAmICalled' called, and how do I isolate it?

**The purpose** is to select the bar (it's an animated bar chart) of one particular country and to apply a particular colour to it, and a different colour to the bars of all the other countries.

I do have this solution if I am dealing only with a **single** dataset:

```
    var myData:Number = dataArray[(numBars-1)-i][currentIndex];
    var myBar:Sprite = new Sprite();
        myBar.name = "bar"+i;
        if (myBar.name == "bar10")
```

... but unfortunately, in this case, I am using **multiple** datasets, and the countries appear in a different order, so the myBar.name route does not work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, bar associated with country and its data.
So you can create class Bar extending of Sprite with appropriate variable for data:

```
public class Bar extends Sprite
{
    public var data:XML;

    public function Bar ()
    {
        super();             
    }
}
```

When initializing your bars set data like:

```
for (var i:int=0; i<xmlData.recordSet.rd.length(); i++)
{
    var bar:Bar = new Bar();
    bar.data = xmlData.recordSet.rd[i];        
}
```

Now every bar knows about its data. You can write conditions:

```
if (myBar.data.@id == "Austria")
    doSomething();
```

Hope, it would help.